# How can i simplify these if-statements?

Tags: java

How can I simplify this and make it still do the same thing?

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HI {public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Welcome1 = "Welcome";
    String specialWelcome1 = "Welcome Parzival";
    String joinLogin1 = "What would you like to do?";
    System.out.println(Welcome1);
    System.out.println("Insert your name below");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Person = scan.nextLine();
    if (Person.equals("Parzival")) {
        System.out.println(specialWelcome1);
        System.out.println(joinLogin1);
        String doing1 = scan.nextLine();
        if(doing1.equals("Kill")) {
            System.out.println("What is the password?");
            String killCode = scan.nextLine();
            if(killCode.equals("OASIS kill")){
                System.out.println("Shutting down...");
            }
        if(doing1.equals("Join Game")) {
            System.out.println("Joining...");
        }
        }
}else {
            System.out.println(Welcome1 + " " + Person);
}}}
```

The code looks messy and it is hard to read. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Questions about cleaning up working code should be asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's messy because you've got all this code in one sprawling *class-function-main-body-of-code-thing*. It's messy because your indentation is pure chaos. It's messy because you've got a lot of duplication and verbosity that could be trimmed down.

Comment: I believe [CodeReview.SE] would be a much better fit for your question. However, make *sure* you read their guides on what they're looking for in a question before posting there: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/25167), [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/25167).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One thing that seems obvious is that you cannot reduce the number of String messages.
However, you can still remove the clutter by replacing consecutive `System.out.println` statements with a single `System.out.println` statement as follows :

Your code :

> System.out.println(specialWelcome1);
>   System.out.println(joinLogin1);

Formatted code :

> System.out.println(specialWelcome1 +"\n"+joinLogin1);

The above formatted code can look ugly for cases where there are many more `System.out.println` statements.In that case you can make good use of indentations as follows:

```
> System.out.println(specialWelcome1 
>               +"\n"+joinLogin1
>               +"\n"+joinLogin2
>               +"\n"+joinLogin3
>               +"\n"+joinLogin4
>               +"\n"+joinLogin5
>               +"\n"+joinLogin6
>               +"\n"+joinLogin7
>               );
```

Also, the switch version by **Suchen Oguri**  is better. You should prefer **switch** statements over if-else as they are better performance-wise. The **if-else** will go on checking conditions one-by-one until it finds one that matches, which is not the case with switch statements.

Comment: an anonymous downvote without any constructive comment doesn't make things better. Let people know what you thought and why you thought that way. There's always a scope for improvement for everyone.

Answer (score -2):

I have not tried to optimize, but just organized with *switch* to understand easily.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HI {public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Welcome1 = "Welcome", specialWelcome1 = "Welcome Parzival", joinLogin1 = "What would you like to do?";

    System.out.println(Welcome1);
    System.out.println("Insert your name below");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Person = scan.nextLine();

    switch(Person) {
        case "Parzival":
            System.out.println(specialWelcome1);
            System.out.println(joinLogin1);
            switch(scan.nextLine()) {
                case "Kill": 
                    System.out.println("What is the password?");
                    if(scan.nextLine().equals("OASIS kill"))
                        System.out.println("Shutting down...");
                    break;
                case "Join Game": 
                    System.out.println("Joining..."); break;
            }       
            break;
        default: 
            System.out.println(Welcome1 + " " + Person);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: if you think 2 nested switches are better than 3 ifs, you got it backwards